# How to replace a constraint in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

i have a Question, "why have i create first a new constraint and then delete the old constraint? 
Why in this order?"

i want underline that my Question is for the sequence, why this sequence?

```sql
 select * from user_constraints;
 alter table unipc add constraint nrcheck check(nr>10);
 alter table unipc drop constraint SYS_C6969254;
```

Comment: To make sure no one else inserts invalid data between your operations?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to have that order of operations. You can delete the old constraint and then create the new constraint and it is a perfectly valid set of commands.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id NUMBER CONSTRAINT constraint_name1 CHECK ( id > 10 )
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( id ) VALUES ( 11 );
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name1;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name2 CHECK ( id > 9 );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=073d8e9e7536aca4ae235ee305826216)

However, if you drop the constraint without a replacement constraint being in place then there will be a period of time when it is possible that an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement could modify the table so that it contains data that is invalid against the constraint and creation of the new constraint would fail.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id NUMBER CONSTRAINT constraint_name1 CHECK ( id > 10 )
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( id ) VALUES ( 11 );
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name1;
INSERT INTO table_name ( id ) VALUES ( 4 );
```

Then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name2 CHECK ( id > 9 );
```

Fails with:

```
ORA-02293: cannot validate (SCHEMA_NAME.CONSTRAINT_NAME2) - check constraint violated
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed65942808e935ceb41098bf82887b9c)

Whereas, if you create the new constraint before dropping the old constraint then the invalid data cannot be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The database does not enforce this ordering.

My guess is that guidance is to ensure that one of the constraints (at least) is always in place on the table.  So, `insert`s and `update`s that take place between the two `alter table` statements have a constraint on the table.